# Use Form.has_changed() validation with Django UpdateView

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to post a message when one or more of the values have changed in an UpdateView. Is this possible to do with [Form.has_changed()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.has_changed) with this generic view? For example:

```
class MyUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = MyModel
    form = MyModelForm
    fields = "__all__"
    template_name = "mymodel_form.html"

    if form.has_changed():
        logger.info("Some values have changed")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the [**`.form_valid(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.form_valid) for this:

```
class MyUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyModelForm
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'mymodel_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.has_changed():
            logger.info('Some values have changed')
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

or if you want to log changes if the form might be invalid as well, you can use [**`.get_form(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form):

```
class MyUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyModelForm
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'mymodel_form.html'

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class=form_class)
        if form.has_changed():
            logger.info('Some values have changed')
        return form
```

Comment: I guess `get_form` might be a better method to do this? The form could have changed even when it is invalid.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: yes. There is some ambigity if it should log changes each time, or only if the changes will persist. Updated the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much @WillemVanOnsem and AbdulAzizBarkat :) When I try the second way of doing it I get an "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'form' referenced before assignment". Any ideas?

Comment: @george_the_frog: there was a typo: it is `form = super().get_form(form_class=form_class)`, you specify the form class with `form_class`, so you will need to change that too.